# select where all values present in List<int>

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a column that has comma separated IDs, I get this into a List in LINQ.

What I need to do is only return DataRows where all values within this list are present in another, I've got it working if any are present but I need all.

Code below:

```
results = 
results.Where(
    d => d["FilterIDs"] != null && // Check the row has FilterIds
    !filterValues.Except(
        d["FilterIDs"].ToString().Split(',').ToList(). // Tokenise the string
        Where(s => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(s)).ToList(). // Filter out bad tokens
        ConvertAll<int>(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)) // Convert all the tokens to ints
        ).Any());
            }
```

So, for example, I have a row that has the 1,2,3,4 in it's column 'FilterIDs'

I then have 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 in my List 'filterValues' - in this instance, this row would be returned.

Another row has 1,8,9 - only 1 matches so this wouldn't be returned.

I've been going round in circles and have lost the will with this so any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have just reversed your `Except` call - you have used `A.Except(B)` when you mean `B.Except(A)`.

That said, here's how I would write this:

```
var query = from row in results
            let filterIds = row["FilterIDs"]
            where filterIds != null
            let numbers = filterIds.ToString()
                                   .Split(',')
                                   .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                                   .Select(int.Parse)
            where !numbers.Except(filterValues).Any()           
            select row;
```

Comment: Thanks Ani, however it still seems to be returning those rows with NULL in the FilterIDs column, will try != DbNull.Value instead of null...

Comment: No luck, it still seems to return ones with NULL in the FIlterIDs :(

Answer (score 0):

I would use [`Enumerable<T>.All()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx):

```
results = results.Where(d => d["FilterIDs" != null &&
    d["FilterIDs"].ToString()
        .Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Select(Int32.Parse)
        .All(f => filterValues.Contains(f)));
```

Comment: As the others unfortunately, i'm getting rows back that have NULL in the filterIDs column for some reason

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
results = 
results.Where(
    d => !d.IsNull("FilterIDs") && // Check the row has FilterIds
         d["FilterIDs"]
           .ToString()
           .Split(',') // Tokenise the string
           .Where(s=>!String.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
           .ConvertAll<int>(s => Convert.ToInt32(s))
           .All(i => filterValues.Contains(i) )
      );
```

Comment: This seems to give the same result, i'm getting rows back that have NULL in the filterIDs column for some reason

Comment: What is the type of `results` and/or `d`?  Are you getting `null` or `DBNull`?

Comment: `d["FilterIDs"]` can't be `null` or the inner query would throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: results is a EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> so i'm guessing filterIDs can be DbNull

Comment: That seems to have an even stranger result, it still seems to be returning where 1 value is present, not all. Would I need to modify it to see if the count of FIlterIDs that are in FilterValues is the same count that's in filterValues?